# Regex for table names in Oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to search tables that are imported with mixed types of letters (upper/lower), therefore I am using a regex. However, this is not the right syntax. Is there a way to implement this in Oracle?

Possible table names:

```
my_TablEnaME_20140501
MY_TablEnaME_20140501
MY_TABLENAME_20140501

SELECT * FROM REGEXP_LIKE(my_TablEnaME_20140502, '[a-zA-Z]', 'i')
```

The problem is when I search like:

```
SELECT * FROM step_factor_20120903
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(jobDateClosed, '[a-z]+.?[A-Z]+|[A-Z]+.?[a-z]', 'c');

Error at Command Line : 121 Column : 15
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

But if I search with quotes such as:

```
SELECT * FROM "step_factor_20120903"
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE("jobDateClosed", '[a-z]+.?[A-Z]+|[A-Z]+.?[a-z]', 'c');
```

I get the results.

What I want to achieve is not to have to use the quotes because the code needs to be dynamic and handle any naming convention of the tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take into consideration that Oracle names are case insensitive unless they are double-quoted ("This is how the SQL standard requires identifiers to be treated").

This query will search for the names which contain both lowercase and uppercase letters (only double-quoted can be found others are stored in uppercase):

```
SELECT * FROM ALL_TABLES 
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(TABLE_NAME, '[a-z]+.?[A-Z]+|[A-Z]+.?[a-z]+', 'c');
```

`ALL_TABLES` contains tables on which a user has any privileges

`USER_TABLES` contains tables owned by a user

`[A-Z]+` at least one uppercase letter

`.?` any symbol 0 or more times

`|` = or

To summarize:

> In a SQL statement, you represent the name of an object with a quoted
>   identifier or a nonquoted identifier.
>   - A quoted identifier begins and ends with double quotation marks ("). **If you name a schema object using a quoted identifier, then you must
>   use the double quotation marks whenever you refer to that object.**
>   - A nonquoted identifier is not surrounded by any punctuation.

Table names are stored in USER_TABLES without quotes. For example:

- name "MyTab" is stored as MyTab
- name MyTab is stored as MYTAB

In order to retrive all the "correct" table names from USER_TABLES you can use this query:

```
select '"' || table_name || '"' from user_tables;
```

because Oracle considers "MYTAB" and MYTAB to be equivalent.

Or you can use this query (but it will found only quoted names which contain lowercase letters, not all quoted names):

```
select case when regexp_like(table_name, '[a-z]', 'c') then '"' || table_name || '"'
else table_name end
from user_tables;
```

Comment: I am getting the following error: Error at Command Line : 122 Column : 19
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "STEP_EUROOUT_20140502": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: @nectarines Which version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: I'm using 11g but some of our databases could be 9i which I haven't tested it on them yet. I'm querying like: SELECT * FROM ALL_TABLES 
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(STEP_EUROOUT_20140502, '[a-z]+.?[A-Z]+|[A-Z]+.?[a-z]+', 'c');

Comment: @nectarines "STEP_EUROOUT_20140502" - should be a column name in the view ALL_TABLES, which is TABLE_NAME

Comment: How should I form the query if my table name is STEP_EUROOUT_20140502 and I want to list all it's contents using the regex?

Comment: @nectarines Describe your table then. Do you want to search for the pattern in this table? which columns? From your question I can only see that you need to find tables with specific names

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64694/discussion-between-multisync-and-nectarines).

Comment: "*Oracle names are case insensitive unless they are double-quoted*" - that is not specific to Oracle. This is how the SQL standard requires identifiers to be treated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select from or search the CONTENT of these Tables you need dynamic SQL!

No Regex is usually needed, since Oracle is by default case-insensitive.

Otherwise you will need a two-step solution in PLSQL:

```
DECLARE
  l_variable1 VARCHAR2(30);
  l_tab       record_table; -- Has to be properly defined on the column-types
BEGIN
  SELECT TABLE_NAME INTO variable1
    FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE LOWER(TABLE_NAME) = LOWER('name_from_csv');
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE( 'SELECT * FROM "' || l_variable1 || '";' ) INTO l_tab;
END;
```